# Detecting EOF without 0-byte read in Rust

Tags: rust, io

I've been working on some code that reads data from a [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) type (the `input`) in chunks and does some processing on each chunk. The issue is that the final chunk needs to be processed with a different function. As far as I can tell, there's a couple of ways to detect EOF from a `Read`, but none of them feel particularly ergonomic for this case. I'm looking for a more idiomatic solution.

My current approach is to maintain two buffers, so that the previous read result can be maintained if the next read reads zero bytes, which indicates EOF in this case, since the buffer is of non-zero length:

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Result};

const BUF_SIZE: usize = 0x1000;

fn process_stream<I: Read>(mut input: I) -> Result<()> {
    // Stores a chunk of input to be processed
    let mut buf = [0; BUF_SIZE];
    let mut prev_buf = [0; BUF_SIZE];
    let mut prev_read = input.read(&mut prev_buf)?;

    loop {
        let bytes_read = input.read(&mut buf)?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            break;
        }

        // Some function which processes the contents of a chunk
        process_chunk(&prev_buf[..prev_read]);

        prev_read = bytes_read;
        prev_buf.copy_from_slice(&buf[..]);
    }

    // Some function used to process the final chunk differently from all other messages
    process_final_chunk(&prev_buf[..prev_read]);
    Ok(())
}
```

This strikes me as a very ugly way to do this, I shouldn't need to use two buffers here.

An alternative I can think of would be to impose [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html) on `input` and use `input.read_exact()`. I could then check for an [`UnexpectedEof`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.UnexpectedEof) errorkind to determine that we've hit the end of input, and seek backwards to read the final chunk again (the seek & read again is necessary here because the contents of the buffer are undefined in the case of an `UnexpectedEof` error). But this doesn't seem idiomatic at all: Encountering an error, seeking back, and reading again just to detect we're at the end of a file is very strange.

My ideal solution would be something like this, using an imaginary `input.feof()` function that returns true if the last `input.read()` call reached EOF, like the [`feof` syscall in C](https://linux.die.net/man/3/feof):

```rust
fn process_stream<I: Read>(mut input: I) -> Result<()> {
    // Stores a chunk of input to be processed
    let mut buf = [0; BUF_SIZE];
    let mut bytes_read = 0;

    loop {
        bytes_read = input.read(&mut buf)?;

        if input.feof() {
            break;
        }

        process_chunk(&buf[..bytes_read]);
    }

    process_final_chunk(&buf[..bytes_read]);
    Ok(())
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to implement this that is more idiomatic? Thanks!

Comment: Forgive me if I completely misunderstood your examples, but doesn't `input.read` not mutate the buffer at all if `bytes_read == 0`? So shouldn't `buf` still have its previous contents? I understood need for `prev_buf` if `buf` got hypothetically cleared when reading EOF, but don't understand need for it otherwise.

Comment: @MarioIshac You're right, I think I got a bit trapped in my own head on this. Because the `Read` documentation doesn't explicitly state that the buffer must not be modified if the number of bytes read is 0, I just didn't think about it, but any well-behaved `Read` should probably not modify the buffer if it's not read anything! If you want to write an answer I'll mark it as correct, otherwise I'll submit one a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: "the final chunk needs to be processed with a different function". This looks like a problem. Why do that?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I think there are reasonable reasons you might want to do that. In my case I'm working with a [stream cipher construction](https://doc.libsodium.org/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream) that requires tagging a final message differently to previous messages. The actual function used is the same, with a different parameter, the code here is just simplified to make my problem clearer.

Comment: I'll write an answer shortly, and will also include a disclaimer regarding what n.'pronouns'm. said, since that affects what is considered the last chunk.

Comment: I see. Indeed it could be reasonable in crypto settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `read` of `std::io::Read` returns `Ok(n)`, not only does that mean that [the buffer `buf` has been filled in with `n` bytes of data from this source.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#required-methods), but it also indicates that the bytes after index `n` (inclusive) are left untouched. With this in mind, you actually don't need a `prev_buf` at all, because when `n` is 0, all bytes of the buffer would be left untoutched (leaving them to be those bytes of the previous read).

prog-fh's solution is what you want to go with for the kind of processing you want to do, because it will only hand off full chunks to `process_chunk`. With `read` potentially returning a value between `0` and `BUF_SIZE`, this is needed. For more info, see this part of the above link:

> It is not an error if the returned value n is smaller than the buffer size, even when the reader is not at the end of the stream yet. This may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (e. g. being close to end-of-file) or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

However, I advise that you think about what should happen when you get a `Ok(0)` from `read` that does not represent end of file forever. See this part:

> If n is 0, then it can indicate one of two scenarios:
>
> 1. This reader has reached its “end of file” and will likely no longer be able to produce bytes. **Note that this does not mean that the reader will always no longer be able to produce bytes.**

So if you were to get a sequence of reads that returned `Ok(BUF_SIZE), Ok(BUF_SIZE), 0, Ok(BUF_SIZE)` (which is entirely possible, it just represents a hitch in the IO), would you want to not consider the last `Ok(BUF_SIZE)` as a read chunk? If you treat `Ok(0)` as EOF forever, that may be a mistake here.

The only way to reliably determine what should be considered as the last chunk is to have the expected length (in bytes, not # of chunks) sent beforehand as part of the protocol. Given a variable `expected_len`, you could then determine the start index of the last chunk through `expected_len - expected_len % BUF_SIZE`, and the end index just being `expected_len` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I definitely appreciate the need for more robust handling of the I/O as in prog-fh's answer.

Comment: "does not mean that the reader will always no longer be able to produce bytes" does not mean that it can return zero bytes as a "hitch". Zero always indicates end of file. It means that some devices (terminals, with their keyboard-commanded EOFs, and maybe files that were appended to (not sure of that one)) may have end-of-file conditions that are not permanent. Zero *does* reliably indicate end of file.

Comment: @KevinReid You're right, my understanding was off when I wrote this. Is it correct instead that because the OS knows that lack of bytes doesn't necessarily mean EOF (since stream wasn't closed yet, or file position hasn't reached recorded file length yet) that it will instead continue blocking instead of returning 0? And only when EOF is intentionally moved like you said can 0 be returned midway? If I got it right, I'll update answer.

Comment: @MarioIshac this is not directly related to Rust, but since you put emphasis on this specific part of the documentation, I'm just curious: how could we obtain Something, Something, Zero and Something again on a read system call? If the file descriptor is non-blocking it should fail with EAGAIN. If the blocking call is interrupted by a signal it should fail with EINTR (or block again). I cannot obtain 0 in any other situation than EOF (the other extremity is closed). How do you manage to obtain 0 in other situations?

Comment: @prog-fh 0 always signifies EOF, but not necessarily EOF forever. Here's an [example I created](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45064d12c4f3a74466bc8909edd3a06b) of what Kevin said above regarding appending to a file. Output is `1, 1, 0, 1`. I don't entirely understand behavior myself (see above comments), but if there are multiple handles on a file I think that's where this would happen (and thus affects what could be considered the "terminal chunk" for OP's special processing).

Comment: The important thing is that under _normal_ conditions of "read an entire file", `Ok(0)` _reliably_ signals the end of the file. The Rust function for reading an entire file, `read_to_string`, uses `Ok(0)` to detect the end. The note in the documentation is saying that it is _possible, in some cases_ for there to be more data, not that you _need_ to handle that case to read a file normally. Every time you've ever hit `^D` in a Unix system to end input to a program, the program is receiving the equivalent of `Ok(0)` and you're _expecting_ the program to stop there. Don't say it should continue.

Answer (score 3):

Since you consider `read_exact()` as a possible solution, then we can consider that a non-final chunk contains exactly `BUF_SIZE` bytes.
Then why not just read as much as we can to fill such a buffer and process it with a function, then, when it's absolutely not possible (because EOF is reached), process the incomplete last chunk with another function?

Note that `feof()` in C does not *guess* that EOF will be reached on the next read attempt; it just reports the EOF flag that could have been set during the previous read attempt.
Thus, for EOF to be set and `feof()` to report it, a read attempt returning 0 must have been encountered first (as in the example below).

**Edit** 
Thanks to @AndreKR 's comment, it seems important for the algorithm to not consider a final chunk of size zero (i.e. when the total amount of bytes in the file is an exact multiple of the expected chunk size).
I adjusted the algorithm consequently (very lately, sorry...) and the
consequence is an extra complexity: we have to hold each full chunk before processing it, just to check if the next one will be empty or not, then decide which chunk can be considered as final or not.

Note that I chose to alternate between two distinct buffers and let the bytes in place, rather than copying the bytes from one container to another.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, Result};

const BUF_SIZE: usize = 0x1000;

fn process_chunk(bytes: &[u8]) {
    println!(
        "process_chunk {} ~~> {:?}...",
        bytes.len(),
        &bytes[..5.min(bytes.len())]
    );
}
fn process_final_chunk(bytes: &[u8]) {
    println!(
        "process_final_chunk {} ~~> {:?}...",
        bytes.len(),
        &bytes[..5.min(bytes.len())]
    );
}

fn process_stream<I: Read>(mut input: I) -> Result<()> {
    // stores two chunks of input in order to postpone
    // their process as final or not
    let mut buffer = [[0; BUF_SIZE]; 2];
    let mut buffer_bytes = [0; 2];
    let mut buffer_idx = 0;
    loop {
        let mut bytes_read = 0;
        let mut eof = false;
        // read a chunk until completion or EOF
        while bytes_read < BUF_SIZE {
            let r = input.read(&mut buffer[buffer_idx][bytes_read..])?;
            if r == 0 {
                eof = true;
                break;
            }
            bytes_read += r;
        }
        buffer_bytes[buffer_idx] = bytes_read;
        if bytes_read != 0 {
            // the previous chunk (if any) was not the final one
            if buffer_bytes[1 - buffer_idx] != 0 {
                process_chunk(&buffer[1 - buffer_idx]);
            }
        }
        if eof {
            if bytes_read == 0 {
                // the previous chunk (if any) was the final one
                if buffer_bytes[1 - buffer_idx] != 0 {
                    process_final_chunk(&buffer[1 - buffer_idx]);
                }
            } else {
                // the (incomplete) current chunk is the final one
                process_final_chunk(&buffer[buffer_idx][..bytes_read]);
            }
            break;
        }
        buffer_idx = 1 - buffer_idx;
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("data.bin").unwrap();
    process_stream(file).unwrap();
}
/*
$ dd if=/dev/random of=data.bin bs=1024 count=9
$ cargo run
process_chunk 4096 ~~> [31, 172, 180, 87, 119]...
process_chunk 4096 ~~> [159, 73, 228, 79, 142]...
process_final_chunk 1024 ~~> [153, 213, 2, 223, 17]...
$ truncate -s 8192 data.bin
$ cargo run
process_chunk 4096 ~~> [31, 172, 180, 87, 119]...
process_final_chunk 4096 ~~> [159, 73, 228, 79, 142]...
*/
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! You're totally correct, and this solution works, but Mario's comment helped me get a bit more insight into exactly where my thinking was wrong on this and how to proceed, so I'll see if they answer and mark that as correct, if that's okay. Cheers!

Comment: This solution doesn't actually work, the output in the second case should be `process_chunk 4096 process_final_chunk 4096`.

Comment: @AndreKR I agree that we could **imagine** that two `read()` operations of 4096 should be sufficient in order to obtain the 8192 bytes of the file (till the EOF), but unfortunately, as soon as we know how the underlying system-calls work it is not possible (EOF detection relies on the zero result). May be should we make the algorithm more complex by holding the last chunk just in case EOF happens right after, and then change the function to be called? But in the example provided in the question, an empty final chunk did not seem to be a problem, so I decided to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Holding the chunk until the next one is read, that's exactly what I had to do [here](https://github.com/RustCrypto/traits/issues/1305#issuecomment-1517136337) (variable `chunk_stash`), where I'm dealing with the same algorithm as OP.

Comment: @AndreKR Thanks for the details. I didn't notice the importance of the non-emptiness of the final chunk in the original problem. I adjusted the algorithm accordingly, with a kind of double-buffering, in order to postpone the decision to consider a chunk as final or not.